# Div as Radio HTML5 CSS Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use radio button as div in bootstrap 3. The result should be: when a user clicks on the div tag, the whole div tag gets highlighted.
Here is the codepen link : http://codepen.io/parthshah000/pen/pyRMdQ

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href="">
        <img class="img-circle" src=" http://placehold.it/42x42" alt="" />
        <span>Title</span>
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href="">
        <img class="img-circle" src=" http://placehold.it/42x42" alt="" />
        <span>Title</span>
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href="">
        <img class="img-circle" src=" http://placehold.it/42x42" alt="" />
        <span>Title</span>
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href="">
        <img class="img-circle" src=" http://placehold.it/42x42" alt="" />
        <span>Title</span>
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio4" value="option4">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap your `<a>` tags for `<label>`s and give them a `cursor: pointer`.
Voilà, see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNxwXR

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, so I may have to extrapolate a bit.

If you're looking to click anywhere in a particular `div` and activate the radio button within it, then wrap your inputs in a `<label ...>` and remove the anchor (`<a>`) tag. This is assuming that you don't want these radio buttons to link to somewhere, but again the intent is very unclear.

As a general rule, a `div` is just an html element that is a blank canvas for you to define how it looks and acts. Anchor tags have very specific role in their functionality on the DOM.

Here's an edit to your codepen with what I believe you're trying to get at:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyJNPd

Comment: You should have added this as a comment, not as an answer. You might get downvoted for that.

Comment: I can't comment on a main post as I don't have enough rep just yet, I'm sorry.